# Angular 9 - date-picker showing wrong date

Tags: angular, date

I'm not sure why the date picker is always showing one day previous. Example if e.Value = "2020-09-17", the data picker will display "9/16/2020" instead of "9/17/2020"

```
 <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" [floatLabel]="'always'">
        <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [disabled]="!editable" [matDatepicker]="j" [value]="e.Value">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="j"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #j></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you hardcode the value, like `value="2020-09-17"` and check? Because I tried hardcoding in the office Stackblitz and it worked fine for me.

Comment: what is e.value
i checked your code it is working gud only
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-datepicker-okb69u?file=app/datepicker-overview-example/datepicker-overview-example.component.html

Comment: You are right,  if i hard code the value it seems to be working. This did the trick  [value]="datePipe.transform(e.Value, 'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00')"